# Spacing between HTML anchor tags

Tags: html, anchor, margin, padding, space

```
<a h ref="*****" >Register</a>  <a h ref="******"> Forgot Password</a>
```

How do I add some space between these two anchor tags? I want to see them in the same line but with adequate space between them. And without adding padding or margin.

It's pretty confusing when trying to add space between any two html tags, like the thing we do with SPACE BAR, 
is there any specific html tag to do that job?

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use padding or margin?

Comment: Did you try `&nbsp;` to insert a space between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try this? Using non breaking spaces-

```
<a href="*****" >Register</a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href="******">Forgot Password</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not good design practice to use spaces to control layout. That is the purpose of CSS. HTML generally tends to strip consecutive successive spaces (unless you use styles to control that). So doing something like this gives you a lot less control:

```
<a href="someref"> Register </a> <a href="someOtherRef">Forgot Password</a>
```

And it would be better to do the following

```
<a href="someref" style="margin-right:5px">Register</a><a href="someOtherRef">Forgot Password</a>
```

Or whatever margin you want. This gives you total and absolute control.

Answer (score 0):

try adding nbsp;between the anchor tags without spacing add as much aaccording to your needs
Register   Forgot Password

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).